# dynamically switch between components not working in VueJS

Tags: vuejs2, vue-component

I practice VueJS with following html and js:

HTML:

```html
<div id="app">
    <ui class="nav nav-tabs">
        <li class="nav-item">
            <a href="#"
            class="nav-link custom"
            @click="currentView = 'home-component'"
            :class="{ 'active': currentView === 'home-component' }">Home</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
            <a href="#"
            class="nav-link custom"
            @click="currentView = 'list-component'"
            :class="{ 'active': currentView === 'list-component' }">List</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
            <a href="#"
            class="nav-link custom"
            @click="currentView = 'about-component'"
            :class="{ 'active': currentView === 'about-component' }">About</a>
        </li>
    </ui>

    <div class="app-body">
        <home-component v-if="currentView === 'home-component'" />
        <list-component v-if="currentView === 'list-component'" />
        <about-component v-if="currentView === 'about-component'" />
    </div>
</div>
```

VueJS:

```js
const vm = new Vue({    
    data() {
        return {
            currentView: 'list-component'
        }
    },
    components: {
        'home-component': {
            template: '<div>Home Component</div>'
        },
        'list-component': {
            template: '<div>List Component</div>'
        },
        'about-component': {
            template: '<div>About Component</div>'
        }
    }
});

vm.$mount('#app');
```

I can't seem to figure out how to make components switch when i click the tab. But when i use `is` special attribute, components work fine:

```html
<div class="app-body">
    <home-component v-bind:is="currentView" />
    <list-component v-bind:is="currentView" />
   <about-component v-bind:is="currentView" />
</div>
```

How do I correctly switch the components when I click the tab without using `is` special attribute ?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<div class="app-body">
    <div :is="currentView" />
</div>
```

this will replace the "div" with the component present on "currentView"

Comment: Almost correct. It's not a `div` but `<component :is="currentView">`